# Upgrade chip in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

When you return to china, and all the Augs start experiencing the weird side effects, what is the result of going to the limb clinic and upgrading your chip vs. not going and upgrading? or does it not matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does matter. Spoiler:

> Just before you fight the third boss, Zhao uses something on you. If you have the upgraded biochip, you essentially have a permanent EMP. Your HUD is messed up, so you don't have a radar, health/battery meter, ammo, etc. I found I was able to use augmentations though (such as looking through walls). I just didn't know how much battery power I had left.

Comment: Maybe yours bugged out because I could not use any augmentations, and neither could anyone else I've spoken to who also upgraded their chip.

Comment: It's possible. I found it very odd that the game acted like I was under the affects of an EMP, but still let me use augs. I also encountered a bug where if I skipped the cutscene I didn't lose my abilities at all. Not sure why my experience was different.

Comment: Note that the negative effect is very short-lived, and is fixed after the battle.

Comment: I have experienced the same effect, and I'm curious as to what happens if you don't replace the chip? Are the effects different, is there a different cutscene?

Answer (score 0):

When you didnt get the LIMB upgrade:

> Zhao uses the device on you to disable your augmentations and fails, she can hardly believe it. Then the boss comes to kill you but will have a difficult time.

Comment: What  about if you do get the upgrade?